# How to bring f(x) from denominator to numerator?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, convolution

Is it possible to rewrite the following ratio in a way that $f(x)$, its powers or derivatives appears only as numerator.
$$\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{c}(c-x)^{2}f(x)dx}$$
$c>0$ is a constant.
$f(x)$ is positive, continuous, and differentiable.
It is allowed to have a specified value of $f(x)$, such as $f(0)$ or $f(c)$, as denominator.
Using series is allowed.

Comment: Have you tried something? Is this question possibly related to what you have seen in class or something like that?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yes, I have tried the integral of convolutions, a corollary of Fubini's theorem, and solving a Volterra integral equation of the first kind. The result is a bit complicated and confusing. I am looking for the simplest representation. The incentive could be to find the expected value of the ratio wherein $f(x)$ is a random field.

Comment: You can apply [Cauchy's formula for repeated integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration). This implies that $\int_0^c (c-x)^2 f(x) dx=f^{(-3)}(c)$, the third anti-derivative of $f$ evaluated at $c$. Given this, you are asking if the reciprocal of some number of anti-derivatives of a function can be written in terms of the original function.

Comment: @EricNaslund : Of course he can do that. I just don't see how it's going somewhere for a general (even analytic) function $f$.